# How to get value from multiple criteria search in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

I am looking for a function or script that will find and return cell value from "database" to "report".
Database has information of all products and stages that have to be made to get finished product. It has also a time of every stage.
In the report sheet I am getting data (that changes everyday) about current production stage.

All I want to know is time left to get finished product.

I have tried query function, but I couldn't find good solution for it because I want to only one value and the column it should be searching for it changes everyday.

So I tried to make my own function but I don't know how to get that one value.
I was able to get the whole row

```
  function searching(product,stage) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dane = ss.getSheetByName("database");
  var dane2 = dane.getRange(2, 1, dane.getLastRow()-1,60).getValues();
  
  var data = dane2.filter(function(item){
                          return item[0] == product && item[1] == stage   ;                 
                          });      
}
```

As you can see this code is not perfect because I am still looking at specific column and "product" "stage" does not work. (not taking values from specific cells)

Anyone has an idea how it could be solved? Regular google sheet function or script will be fine.

Here you have a link to sheet:
[Production Stage and time left](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SaGo-yA6YPP-Um68Sgm8H3yMyfqXclDQWl5_l4cxgs4/edit?usp=sharing)

Will be very grateful for any advice!

Comment: When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, there are 2 `DEF` of the 2nd row (product "ABC") in `database` sheet. But there is only one `DEF` of the 2nd row (product "ABC") at `Report` sheet. So I cannot understand about your goal. Can you provide the detail logic for achieving your goal and also, can you add the sample output you expect to your shared Spreadsheet?

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for your reply!
it is because to currently product "ABC" passed the DEF stage and now is on GHI stage
"Report" sheet shows the current state of production.
So to make product "ABC" you have to go through DEF -> GHI -> JKL -> DEF
ABC is now on GHI stage.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your case, the value of "C2" in "database" sheet is not used. You want to use only the value of "I2". For example. when "DEF" is existing in the cell "J2", you want to use the value of the cell "K2" as the value of "DEF". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike yes, that's correct!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. At first, please test the script using your shared Spreadsheet. This sample script is for it. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64421869/google-sheet-return-values-based-on-match

Here I posted another question

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would like to check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from database sheet.
- You want to check the product name and stage name, and want to put the value of time to the Report sheet.

  - In your shared Spreadsheet, the value of "C2" in "database" sheet is not used. You want to use only the value of "I2". For example. when "DEF" is existing in the cell "J2", you want to use the value of the cell "K2" as the value of "DEF".
- You want to achieve the following situation. (This is from your shared Spreadsheet.)

  - From

    [image]
  - To

    [image]
- The structures of the column headers of each sheet are always same. The name of stage and value of time are the different.
- You want to achieve above using Google Apps Script.

In order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose the following flow.

1. Retrieve the source values from database sheet.
2. Create an object for searching each stage from the values of database sheet.
3. Retrieve the source values from Report sheet.
4. Create an array for putting to Spreadsheet using the created object.
5. Put the created array to Report sheet.

When above flow is reflected to the script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // 1. Retrieve the source values from database sheet.
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("database");
  const srcValues = srcSheet.getRange(2, 1, srcSheet.getLastRow()-1, srcSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
  // 2. Create an object for searching each stage from the values of database sheet.
  const srcObj = srcValues.reduce((o, [a, ...v]) => {
    const temp = {};
    while (v.length > 0) {
      const [stage, time] = v.splice(0, 2);
      if (stage && time > 0) {
        temp[stage] = time;
      }
    }
    o[a] = temp;
    return o;
  }, {});
  
  // 3. Retrieve the source values from Report sheet.
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Report");
  const dstValues = dstSheet.getRange(2, 1, dstSheet.getLastRow()-1, dstSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
  // 4. Create an array for putting to Spreadsheet using the created object.
  const dstArray = dstValues.reduce((ar, [a, b, ...v]) => {
    let temp = [];
    if (srcObj.hasOwnProperty(a)) {
      while (v.length > 0) {
        const [stage,] = v.splice(0, 2);
        temp = temp.concat(stage, stage && srcObj[a].hasOwnProperty(stage) ? srcObj[a][stage] : "");
      }
    }
    ar.push(temp);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  
  // 5. Put the created array to Report sheet.
  dstSheet.getRange(2, 3, dstArray.length, dstArray[0].length).setValues(dstArray);
}
```

#### Note:

- This sample script is prepared for your shared Spreadsheet. So when the structures of the column headers of each sheet are changed, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: That works great! Thanks a lot! 
What if column will change? Where in the code should I look for changes?
Is it in this part `const srcObj = srcValues.reduce((o, [a, ...v]) => {`
`const dstArray = dstValues.reduce((ar, [a, b, ...v]) =>`

Comment: @Pimo Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `What if column will change? Where in the code should I look for changes?`, unfortunately, I cannot understand about the detail of it. So I cannot propose the clear answer. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. When you want to change the structure of header row, I would like to recommend to post it as new question. Because in this case, the script might be required to be large change and this sample script is for the sample Spreadsheet of your this question.

Comment: @Pimo I deeply apologize that my proposed answer cannot be used for various situations. This is due to my poor skill again. I deeply apologize for this. I think that I have to study more.

Comment: don't worry about that! it works great for me and I can always adjust my to fit the template! I was just wondering if I ever do similar job to this one but the return columns will be different and how should I rewrite the code than :)

Comment: What if I would like to return two columns not one?
For example now I am returning only D column but what if I would like to get D and E?
lets say that I have two times: 準備時間と加工時間

Comment: @Pimo Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your new question. In order to correctly understand about your new question, can you post it as new question by including more information? By this, I would like to think of the solution. And also it will help users think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: I dont know why but the code started to give error and it stop returning value
`[20-10-18 23:32:47:846 PDT] Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 0 but the range has 40.
    at Kako(Code:39:64)` 
Do you have any idea why it happened? The real spreadsheet has more columns and rows than sample. How can I change range in this code?

Comment: @Pimo Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot understand about the detail of your new issue. Because when I tested my script for your sample Spreadsheet, no error occurs. Unfortunately, my answer is for your sample Spreadsheet. When you used my script for other structure, the script might not be able to be used. This has already been mentioned. I deeply apologize that my proposed answer cannot be used for various situations. This is due to my poor skill again. But when I got the same issue with your replying, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: @Pimo If your actual Spreadsheet is different from your provided sample Spreadsheet, can you post it as new question by including more information for replicating your issue? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Yes, I know but where in the code is that 40 column range?
もうようわからん　笑　非表示に原本データが入っています。

Comment: @Pimo When I tested your provided sample Spreadsheet again, unfortunately, no error occurs. I apologize for this. When I could correctly replicate your new issue, I would like to think of the solution. By the way, if your current Spreadsheet is different from your provided sample Spreadsheet, can you post your new issue by including the sample Spreadsheet and your current script for replicating your issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64423026/how-can-i-get-value-from-a-search-in-database-and-return-it-to-the-report-multi

posted new question

Comment: @Pimo Thank you for your response. I would like to check it.